# `decltype` and mixing ADL-lookup with non-ADL-lookup

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, argument-dependent-lookup

### Testcase

Let the return type of a function `auto foo(T f)` be the same as when calling `sin(f)` from header `cmath` in cases where `f` is an intrinsic datatype:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T f) -> decltype(sin(f))
{
    using std::sin;
    return sin(f);
}
```

This is broken. The `sin(f)` within `decltype` is not looked up within `std`, hence only the `C` variant `sin(double)` is found, whose return type is `double`. The following program demonstrates that:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace meh {
    struct Nanometer {};
    struct SinfulNanometer {};
    SinfulNanometer sin(Nanometer) { return SinfulNanometer(); }
}

template <typename T>
auto foo(T f) -> decltype(sin(f))
{
    using std::sin;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(sin(f))).name() << '\n';
}


int main () {
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(foo(0.))).name() << '\n'
              << typeid(decltype(foo(0.f))).name() << '\n'
              << typeid(decltype(foo(meh::Nanometer()))).name() << '\n';
              
    foo(0.);
    foo(0.f);
    foo(meh::Nanometer());
}
```

Output:

```
d
d
N3meh15SinfulNanometerE
d
f
N3meh15SinfulNanometerE
```

The output suggests that the return type is always `double` for `foo->float` *and* `foo->double`, only *within* `foo()`, the correct `sin(float|double)` is found because of the `using std::sin`, which imports all overloads.

I wonder if such case was taken into consideration in the gremium already, but that's not my question.

### Question

My question is:

What is a sensible way to let `foo` have the same return-type as a function whose name is either in `namespace std` or ADL-looked-up?

Non working workaround:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T f) -> decltype(std::sin(f)); // Will miss sin(Nanometer)
```

Standard proposal?

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T f) -> decltype(using std::sin; sin(f));
```

Using permutations of `enable_if` is in the way of code being self-documenting. `enable_if` is a nice exercise of metaprogramming. But to get a quick grasp of a seemingly simple function, imho not the right thing, therefore not in the spirit of maintainability.

---

edit: I am also using `decltype` to use SFINAE less obscurely, so C++14 with it's new `auto foo() {....}` declarations might not be of help.

Comment: In C++14 you will be able to just use `auto`; no `decltype` needed.

Comment: @rightfold: Will this also work as a SFINAE substitute? Right now, I am also using `decltype` for SFINAE techniques.

Comment: I’m not completely sure about SFINAE here.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/std-proposals

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I wonder if voting for close the own question would be worth a badge, because I just did :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a detail namespace and some wrapping:

```
namespace detail {
    using std::sin;

    template<typename T>
    auto foo(T f) -> decltype(sin(f)) { return sin(f); }
}

template<typename T>
auto foo(T f) -> decltype(detail::foo(f)) { return detail::foo(f); }
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's nice. Everything can be solved with one more indirection :P

Comment: +1 Basically a good solution, except for the name `detail` as this will probably be used quite often in larger project and you just injected `using std::sin;` - this is the reason I used a more specific namespace name for this case to contain the `using`.

Comment: @DanielFrey: I agree on that, I just see `detail` as a placeholder here. I am going to name it appropriately, something like `intrinsic_or_adl` or `mixin_cmath_names`, something. Actually, I am talking about the whole `cmath` header that I overloaded for an RGB-triplet, and which I now want to generalize to work with any array-indexable type.

Answer (score 8):

You need one level of indirection:

```
namespace find_sin
{
    using std::sin;
    template<typename T>
    using type = decltype(sin(std::declval<T>()));
}

template <typename T>
find_sin::type<T> foo(T f)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's nice. Everything can be solved with one more indirection :P Unfortunately, rightfold was some 0.7 secs faster.